# ¿Como puedo hacer la siguiente actualizacion en mysql?

Tags: mysql

tengo una base de datos de clientes donde almaceno las extensiones telefónicas de todos.
La consulta que debo hacer es reemplazar todas las extensiones telefónicas que empiecen por 8 y cambiarlas a que empiecen por 9. Por ejemplo:

856-->956
813-->913

De antemano, he de decir que soy un novato en esto de my sql...
He estado probando con la siguiente sentencia:

update table_name set column_name= replace(column_name, '8%%', '9%%');

Con esta consulta no me da ningún error pero no me hace la actualizacion.

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cómo está definida la columna? No es lo mismo si, por ejemplo, es un varchar que si es un int.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo tomando la parte de la derecha de la columna, excepto el primer carácter, y usando `CONCAT` para agregarle el valor que quieres, `9` en este caso.

La consulta quedaría así:

```
UPDATE table_name SET
    column_name = CONCAT( '9',RIGHT(column_name,LENGTH(column_name)-1))
WHERE column_name LIKE '8%';
```

Funciona, tanto si la columna fuese `INT` o si fuese `VARCHAR`.

Aquí te dejo un fiddle:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  column_name INT,
  column_varchar VARCHAR(12)
  
);
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name,column_varchar) VALUES (881,'881');
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name,column_varchar) VALUES (882,'882');
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name,column_varchar) VALUES (188,'188');

UPDATE table_name SET
    column_name = CONCAT('9',RIGHT(column_name,LENGTH(column_name)-1))
WHERE column_name LIKE '8%';

UPDATE table_name SET
column_varchar = CONCAT('9',RIGHT(column_varchar,LENGTH(column_varchar)-1))
WHERE column_varchar like '8%';
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

| column_name | column_varchar |
| --- | --- |
| 981 | 981 |
| 982 | 982 |
| 188 | 188 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hyLd46HNBSYBvxs5acXjck/0)

Comment: Has resuelto mi duda, muchas gracias compañero.

Comment: Por si le interesa saber, he averiguado otra forma incluso mas sencilla de hacer esta consulta que es la siguiente: update table_name set column_name=replace(column_name,8,9) where column_name like'8%';

Comment: @ProgrammDam la consulta que mencionas no hace lo que indicas en la pregunta: *La consulta que debo hacer es reemplazar todas las extensiones telefónicas que empiecen por 8 y cambiarlas a que empiecen por 9*, pues dicha consulta cambiará **todos los 8 por 9**, en la pregunta se entiende que quieres cambiar solamente el primer valor.

Answer (score 0):

Supondré que es una columna de texto. Prueba REGEXP_REPLACE en lugar de REPLACE. REPLACE busca la cadena exacta, tu estás buscando cambiar en base a una expresión regular.

Comment: Tal vez esto debería ser un comentario, como respuesta no le estás aportando mucho.